# How can i lock my Clash of Clans account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm expected to be going interstate for about 2 or 3 weeks soon (business related) and I plan on leaving my iPad at home (mainly because I'm already taking Yomi, Index and Fate with me and it's either those 3 or the iPad, I rather those 3), so when I'm gone I want to lock my account to stop players from stealing my resources, particularly those sitting in mines/collectors.

I can just buy some Gems to get all the shields but their total is only about 13 days which isn't long enough, and I don't have anyone I can relay on to manage my game for me. I'm wondering if there is a way for me to lock my game while I am way? Will my resources still pool or will my entire game be frozen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really protect everything, especially if you're leaving for a long while.  I don't really think buying shields is worth the gems, myself.  Even with a purchased shield, you can't protect yourself for that long.

After it runs out, you're going to get hit at least a couple of times a day, but you can minimize the impact of each hit.

I'd suggest several things:

- **Drop trophies ahead of time.**  Go fight everyone and drop one archer on every base.  The lower your trophy level, the less strong opponents will find you, generally speaking.  You can always recover later when you return.
- **Move your Town Hall outside your base, and put it as close to the center of the map as possible.**  When someone views your base, they'll start centered on the map.  If they can see your Town Hall, the chances are greater that they'll attack you just for trophies.  This earns you an instant 12 hr shield.
- **Strategically place your collectors.**  Try to place them in spots where an archer or a barb won't attack them first.  Don't group similar collectors together.  Leaving your collectors exposed when you leave for a long time increases the odds that someone will do a cheap [BARCH-style raid](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/tips-tricks-rapid-raiding-around-town-hall-7-clash-clans/) on your base.
- **Spend what you can out of your storages.**  If your storages are deep inside your base, make them as empty as possible so people aren't incented to hit them.  You can store a decent amount of elixir and dark elixir in your barracks via [overtraining](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/10-more-clash-of-clans-strategies-tactics-and-tricks/), for instance.  Gold can be blown on walls.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to prevent being attacked other than [shields](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Shields) can.

I would recommend spending all of your resources on upgrades before you leave, so that attackers have nothing to steal. On the other hand, changing your base to a farming layout will divert an attackers atention from your loot to your town hall.

An example of a TH9 farming layout (town hall outside walls):

[image]

<sup>Image from [this thread](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/228374-COMPILATION-Best-TH9-farming-bases) on the Clash of Clans forum</sup>

Comment: thats a sexy base tho...is it yours?

Comment: @Neffer_23 No it isn't :)